# How do I remove all equipment from a unit in SQF?

Tags: sqf

Say I have a unit `_unit` in Arma 3. How do I remove all its equipment so that the only thing remaining is its uniform?

So far, I have been using

```
removeAllItemsWithMagazines _unit;
{player removeWeaponGlobal _x} forEach weapons _unit;
removeBackpackGlobal _unit;
removeVest _unit;
```

but I am not sure this removes everything.

Notice that *everything* here includes the map, compass, watch and gps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the `Remove existing items` section from [Arsenal loadout exports](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Arsenal#Export_to_SQF):

```
removeAllWeapons this;
removeAllItems this;
removeAllAssignedItems this;
removeUniform this;
removeVest this;
removeBackpack this;
removeHeadgear this;
removeGoggles this;
```

So simply delete the `removeUniform this;` line.